# Why is this contact form not posting an email to me?

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP/HTML I had them on one document for cleanliness. I'm unsure as to why the email isn't showing up in my inbox.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "jordan.summers1998@g.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    header('Location: http://1673-itstudies/12-infotech/jsummers/Carsales_Network.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Contact_US_CSS.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Auto Network</h1>

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br></p>
<p>Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

There is CSS connected however obviously this isn't causing the issue. I'm not sure if the data isn't posting or what's going on.

Comment: Is the sender getting his copy?

Comment: Have you checked the outgoing mail log on the server to see if it's sending the message?

Comment: The code itself looks fine. It could be getting blocked by spam filters, or maybe you don't have the mailserver configured correctly. There's not enough information here for us to tell why it isn't getting through.